# Function Over Loading in GO using interfaces

Tags: go

I have a "main type" and a "sub-type" is embedded in that.Both main and sub implements an interface.

When I'm assigning a 'main type' variable to interface type variable and call implemented method using that interface variable,It calls "main type" implementation not sub type's.I need to call sub-types implementation.

Is it possible in GO ? I think my code design is having some problem. Here I'm giving a sample code to describe this problem.

```
  package main

  import "fmt"

 type interf interface{
      typeCheck()
 }

 type maintype struct{ 
 subtype
 }

 type subtype struct {}

  func (maintype) typeCheck () {
        fmt.Println("Hi,this is printed in Main type")
 }

func (subtype) typeCheck () {
        fmt.Println("Hi,this is printed in Sub-type")
 }





 func main() {
   var intr interf
   var maintp maintype
   intr = maintp
    intr.typeCheck()//Out :"Hi,this is printed in Main type" I need "Hi,this is printed in Sub-type" 
    }
```

PlayGround : http://play.golang.org/p/ut5XPiED75

Kindly Help....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to explicitly assign to your interface the embedded subtype:

```
func main() {
    var intr interf
    var maintp maintype
    intr = maintp.subtype  // <====
    intr.typeCheck()
}
```

output (<kbd>[play.golang.org](http://play.golang.org/p/vI4t5mlRhU)</kbd>):

```
Hi,this is printed in Sub-type
```

The article "[Inheritance Semantics in Go](http://tech.t9i.in/2014/01/inheritance-semantics-in-go/)" details why it doesn't work, in the "Type Embedding and Implementation Inheritance" section.
Its solution is in "Type Substitution Through Interfaces"

> Go accomplishes type substitution through the use of Interfaces.
>   Interfaces allow us to define an abstract behaviour and have different types satisfy that behaviour.

It still relies on affecting the right subtype to the interface variable though.

Comment: Suppose sub-type is not implementing interface ,it has only one method with same name as in interface ,in that case 'intr = maintp.subtype' statement will not work I think(kindly clarify) ..But in this case answer is correct.

Comment: @faisalkk that is why I mentioned the article: it relies on subtype implementing the interface to work.

Comment: I could see your explanation now after refreshing page.Thanks for your help !!

Answer (score 2):

For example,

```
package main

import "fmt"

type interf interface {
    typeCheck()
}

type subtype struct{}

func (subtype) typeCheck() {
    fmt.Println("Hi,this is printed in Sub-type")
}

type maintype struct {
    subtype
}

func (maintype) typeCheck() {
    fmt.Println("Hi,this is printed in Main type")
}

func main() {
    var intr interf
    var maintp maintype
    intr = maintp
    // "Hi,this is printed in Main type"
    intr.typeCheck()
    // "Hi,this is printed in Sub-type"
    intr.(maintype).subtype.typeCheck()
}
```

Output:

```
Hi,this is printed in Main type
Hi,this is printed in Sub-type
```

Comment: Working great!! Thanks for you Help :)